# Where to put sound files in java project?

Tags: java, audio, netbeans

I am adding sounds to my java project that I am making with NetBeans. Where is the best place to  put the sound file? In the package? The source folder? Libraries? Make a new folder? Where is the best place to put it?

Comment: Depends on how you're loading them...

Comment: I'm creating a new URL with getResource() and using newAudioClip() to create the sound.

Answer (score 2):

Depending, if your app is made to be portable - as in just a single jar file - which can be executed without the need of worrying about where resources are located, I'd suggest packaging all resources in your jar file in a separate package and then accessing them using `getResourceAsStream`. See my answer here for extracting resources not contained in your main package: [Exporting jars with resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029412/exporting-jars-with-resources/12029583#12029583). This also helps end users to not accidentally delete a resource or resources' folder.

However, if your application is *installed* on the user machine i.e *Program Files*, then it would be fine to keep it in a separate folder inside your apps folder as the user is not moving your app from PC to PC and thus wont forget to copy any resources.